# Crontab does not launch when log out

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, crontab, cronjob

On a google Cloud Ubuntu VM, I have setup few crontab like below :

```
0 15 * * * sudo /home/username/bin/python /home/username/project27/scheduler/batch.py   &>> /home/username/project27/scheduler/log_batch.txt 


1) Crontab worked if I remain login in SSH session.
2) As soon as I close the SSH session the crontab job is not launched.
```

What's wrong with this ?

How to find the issue ?

Comment: encrypted home? + the concerns stated in the answer bellow ...

Comment: Looked in /var/log/cron ?

Comment: yes, looked in cron log

Answer (score -1):

- In /etc/crontab used in Ubuntu, the 6th item is an id used to run the command, so it should be `root` (or `project27`) instead of `sudo`.
- `/home/bin/python`? Really?

Comment: updated the paths....

Comment: `/home/username/bin/python` still doesn't look like a valid place for a python interpreter... And you confirm the `sudo`?